# Restore intellisense after ReSharper trial expires

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have a C# license for ReSharper, and a little while ago Jetbarins gave me a license key for a 30 day trial of ReSharper full. This has expired and I have gone back to ReSharper C#, and as a result have completely lost VB intellisense.

How do I restore normal VB.Net intellisense from within Visual Studio? Is there a way to do this without resetting all Visual Studio settings (I have changed a number of settings, don't want to have to go through and change them all again).

Comment: Have you tried contacting JetBrains?

Comment: I guess I will do that, thought this might be a common occurrence, and somebody would quickly say "Ah you do this...", thanks

Comment: If you keep this question around, you should probably include a link to this question in your message to them so they know to make sure this is answered as well. :)

Comment: Good point, willdo, cheers

Comment: Sent an email, linked to this question, waiting for a response :)

Answer (score 17):

I had this same problem after my ReSharper trial expired.

The fix is to go to **Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages**.

Then under Statement completion, ensure 'Auto list members' and 'Parameter information' are checked (for me they were partially selected)

Comment: I also needed to restart visual studio to see it working again.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for VS2013, you can go into Tools>Options and find Resharper as it's own menu item there, then click suspend.

It seems to undo all the changes it made at this point and restore my original settings.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider reenabling errors in about the same place:  Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced

Under "Editor Help" section, recheck:

Underline errors in the editor
Show live semantic errors

Source: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104078-Visual-Studio-IntelliSense-is-broken-after-uninstalling-suspending-ReSharper